# My AddLayer script doesn't work within a model but works well on its own

Tags: arcpy, python

I'm trying to write a script in order to add a output to display
(For some reasons I want add the data using a script)
This is my script:

```
import arcpy.mapping as mapping

mxd = mapping.MapDocument("current")

Input = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
df = mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
print df.name
    layer = mapping.Layer(Input)
print layer.name
mapping.AddLayer(df, layer,"TOP")

# Refresh things
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
arcpy.RefreshTOC()
```

It adds the data without any problem when I run it individually. (Not as a step of a model)
But when I add it to a model, as a final step, it does not work or either doesn't generate any error. It seems that the model skips or ignores the script and I don't understand why.
Can anyone help me please?

This is the model sample :
[image]

This is the script properties:
[image]

Comment: In your script try setting the output parameter to be your layer then it should appear as a green bubble in modelbuilder which you can set to add to display?

Comment: Thanks @Hornbydd. Do you know how can I write a line in the script so that  the it generates OUTPUT ? (because I thought the AddLayer function is not capable of the output thing)

Comment: Search help file for SetParameter, you will see code examples.